# C#: Put member variables into a list

Tags: c#, list

Assuming I have a method which accepts an IList or similar thing as a parameter:

```
public void JiggleMyList(IList<string> list)...
```

Is there an easy way that I can pass in string members of a list of objects?

I mean, if for example, I have a list of Person objects which expose a string property called FullName, is there a quick way to stuff the FullNames of all the Person objects into the method parameter, or do I have to create a new List and iterate through the Person objects:

```
List<string> fullNames = new List<string>;
foreach (Person person in people)
{
  fullNames.Add(person.FullName);
}
JiggleMyList(fullNames);
```

I come across this all the time, and it would be nice if there was a shortcut.

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, then you can write this using LINQ:

```
JiggleMyList(people.Select(p => p.FullName).ToList());
```

The `Select` method takes a lambda expression that is used to convert each object from the source collection to some new value and these new values are collected into `IEnumerablt<T>` type. The `ToList` extension method converts this to `List<T>`.

Alternatively, you can write the same thing using query syntax:

```
JiggleMyList((from p in people select p.FullName).ToList());
```

Similar feature is also available in .NET 2.0 (C# 2.0) and you could use anonymous delegate instead of (more elegant) lambda expressions:

```
JiggleMyList(people.ConvertAll(delegate (Person p) { return p.FullName; }));
```

Comment: I really need a book on c# 3!

Answer (score 1):

var list = people.ConvertAll(x=>x.FullName).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
people.ToList().ForEach(person => fullNames.Add(person.FullName));
```